# Matrix form for conjugate linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, matrices

I knew that every linear transformation has matrix representation. I wonder whether I could have a matrix representation for conjugate linear transformation. By conjugate linear transformation, I mean under scalar multiplication instead of $C(af)=aC(f)$, I would have $C(af)= \overline{a} C(f)$, where $a$ is a constant complex number, and $C$ is the transformation.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Given a linear-conjugate function $C: V \longrightarrow V$, $V$ a complex vector space, we define the conjugate vector space $\overline{V}$, by being the **same set** $V$, with an altered multiplication by scalar $\ast$, defined by $$\lambda \ast x := \overline{\lambda} \cdot x $$
where $\cdot$ is $V$'s usual multiplication. See the notations, $V = (V, +, \cdot)$, and $\overline{V} = (V, +, \ast)$. I reforce, the set of vectors is the same. It should be checked that $\overline{V}$ is indeed a vector space, although it's easy to see. Some facts are:

**i)** a set $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V$ iff it is a basis for $\overline{V}$;

**ii)** from **i)** follows that $\dim V = \dim \overline{V}$;

**iii)** $W$ is a subspace of $V$ iff it is a subspace of $\overline{V}$;

**iv)** Given a basis $\mathcal{B}$, $x \in V$ has coordinates $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)_\mathcal{B}$ iff considering $x \in \overline{V}$, we have $x = (\overline{x_1}, \cdots, \overline{x_n})_\mathcal{B}$;

**v)** $C: V \rightarrow V$ is linear conjugate iff $C: \overline{V} \rightarrow{V}$ is linear iff $C: V \rightarrow \overline{V}$ is linear;

**vi)** $\overline{\overline{V}} = V $

Using this construction, you can use everything you already know.

Comment: Thanks so much. Another I want to ask is that can I just use LaTex commend in stackexchange? like $\overline{x}$.... any difference?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just be sure to put the formulas or whatever between \$s