# A question about conjugations on C1 and C2

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over the complex numbers. A function $J$ from $V$ into $V$ is called a *conjugation(or semilinear)* if $J(\alpha+ \beta)=J(\alpha)+J(\beta)$, $J(c\beta)=\bar c J(\beta)$,
and $J(J(\beta)=\beta$ for all scalars $c$ and all $\alpha,\beta$ in $V$.

**Determine all conjugations on $\mathbb C^1$ and $\mathbb C^2$.**

I have no idea how to do this exercise. I know only one example of conjugation that comes from a previous exercise that is $J(\alpha+ i\beta)=\alpha- i\beta$. does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Linear functions have the property that they are entirely defined by their value at a basis. Does the the first two conditions establish a similar property for conjugations? If you give a conjugation some arbitrary values at a basis, what happens when you apply the third condition?

Comment: you can multiply  by a complex number whose magnitude is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Exercise 15 of Section 8.1 in *[Linear Algebra](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit),* second edition, by Hoffman and Kunze.

The first two defining properties of a conjugation show that it is a "conjugate linear transformation." As such, the analogue of Theorem 1 of Section 3.1 (page 69) shows that a conjugation $J$ is completely defined by its action on a basis for $\Bbb C^1$. Because $\Bbb C^1$ has dimension one, its basis has only one vector, say $\epsilon$ (a complex number). Any vector in $\Bbb C^1$, therefore, has the form $c\epsilon$ where $c$ is a scalar (also a complex number) so that $J(\epsilon) = c\epsilon$ for some $c$. The third defining property of a conjugation requires that $J(J\epsilon) =\epsilon$ whereas a calculation shows that $J(J\epsilon) = J(c\epsilon) =\overline c J(\epsilon) =\overline c c\epsilon =\lvert c\rvert^2\epsilon$. Thus, all conjugations on $\Bbb C^1$ are those for which $\lvert c\rvert = 1$.

Next, let $\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$ be a basis for $\Bbb C^2$ so that $J$ is defined by\begin{gather*}
J\epsilon_1 = c_{11}\epsilon_1 + c_{12}\epsilon_2\\
J\epsilon_2 = c_{21}\epsilon_1 + c_{22}\epsilon_2\end{gather*}
where the $c_{ij}$ are scalars. As before, the third defining property of a conjugation requires that $J(J\epsilon_1) =\epsilon_1$, $J(J\epsilon_2) =\epsilon_2$ whereas calculations show that\begin{align*}
J(J\epsilon_1) & = J(c_{11}\epsilon_1 + c_{12}\epsilon_2)\\
& =\overline{c_{11}}J\epsilon_1 +\overline{c_{12}}J\epsilon_2\\
& =\overline{c_{11}}(c_{11}\epsilon_1 + c_{12}\epsilon_2) +\overline{c_{12}}(c_{21}\epsilon_1 + c_{22}\epsilon_2)\\
& =\bigl(\lvert c_{11}\rvert^2 +\overline{c_{12}}c_{21}\bigr)\epsilon_1 + (\overline{c_{11}}c_{12} +\overline{c_{12}}c_{22})\epsilon_2,\\[1ex]
J(J\epsilon_2) & = J(c_{21}\epsilon_1 + c_{22}\epsilon_2)\\
& =\overline{c_{21}}J\epsilon_1 +\overline{c_{22}}J\epsilon_2\\
& =\overline{c_{21}}(c_{11}\epsilon_1 + c_{12}\epsilon_2) +\overline{c_{22}}(c_{21}\epsilon_1 + c_{22}\epsilon_2)\\
& = (\overline{c_{21}}c_{11} +\overline{c_{22}}c_{21})\epsilon_1 +\bigl(\overline{c_{21}}c_{12} +\lvert c_{22}\rvert^2\bigr)\epsilon_2.\end{align*}
Thus, all conjugations on $\Bbb C^2$ are those for which\begin{align*}
\lvert c_{11}\rvert^2 +\overline{c_{12}}c_{21} & = 1\\
\overline{c_{11}}c_{12} +\overline{c_{12}}c_{22} & = 0\\
\overline{c_{21}}c_{11} +\overline{c_{22}}c_{21} & = 0\\
\overline{c_{21}}c_{12} +\lvert c_{22}\rvert^2 & = 1.\end{align*}
For an analysis of those equations, see
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3741833.

For example, two solutions are $J$ defined by $J\epsilon_1 = c_{11}\epsilon_1$, $J\epsilon_2 = c_{22}\epsilon_2$ where $\lvert c_{11}\rvert = 1 =\lvert c_{22}\rvert$, and $J$ defined by $J\epsilon_1 = (1 + i)\epsilon_2/\sqrt2$, $J\epsilon_2 = (1 + i)\epsilon_1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: How do you guarantee the map we got is a conjugate linear transformation? I mean it is quite possible the map we get is just a linear map. How the first two defining properties are guaranteed?

Comment: @Beginner The first two defining properties are guaranteed because they are given to us in the statement of the exercise. Then $J$ is a conjugate linear transformation by definition (e.g., see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853538/matrix-form-for-conjugate-linear-transformation)). The map we get is not linear if $V$ is not the zero vector space because $J(i\beta)\neq iJ(\beta)$ for all $\beta$. See MBW's comment.

Comment: So you mean, for example, when we get this $J$, $J\epsilon_1 = (1 + i)\epsilon_2/\sqrt2$, $J\epsilon_2 = (1 + i)\epsilon_1/\sqrt2$ in your answer, when we try to do explicit calculation in the vector space $V$, we just force(by definition) $J(cv)$ and $J(v_1)+J(v_2)$ are calculated according to first two definitions, then we are good.

Comment: @Beginner Yes. But just to be clear, we "force" all three parts of the definition of a conjugation to get example conjugations. Once we have an example conjugation, it automatically satisfies the definition when we do explicit calculations.